# DB2 SQL column percentage calculation

Tags: sql, statistics, db2

Need to calculate a percentage of filled rows in a column(string).

String column could contain zero length strings (should be excluded)

How to re-write this SQL in one sentence (without WITH operator)?

```
          with A(COUNT)  // needed rows
             as(
                 select count(FAMILY) from T1 
                    where length(FAMILY)>0
               ),
               B(COUNT) // total rows
             as(
                 select count(*) from T1)

         select A.COUNT*100/B.COUNT from A,B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sub-selects instead of WITH; for example:

```
select
  ((select count(*) from T1 where length(FAMILY) > 0) * 100) /
  (select count(*) from T1)
from sysibm.sysdummy1
```